# Left touchpad button doesn't work after upgrade to 12.04

Tags: touchpad, xserver

Since I installed an upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, my left button (Touchpad) doesn't work well.

This means I have to log out via [<kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctrl-Alt-Del) then log in again.

Before I log out, I can move the cursor, but the left click is unresponsive.

Somewhere I read it has to do something with the XServer and I have to restart.

I own an Fujitsu Lifebook AH530 and I can't find any touchpad or mouse drivers for it.

Answer (score 0):

A patch for this issue that I've used before on a particular situation for a specific laptop (can remember the brand):

This ppa provides xserver-xorg-input-synaptics patched to provide support for Clickpads.

[available in sergio’s ppa](https://launchpad.net/~sergio91pt/+archive/synaptics+clickpads)

open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sergio91pt/synaptics+clickpads
```

and after

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This patch fix the problem with click buttons (located at the bottom of the trackpad), left and right click are ok with it.

A more comprehensive document about **Touchpad Synaptics** can be [found here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics).